# Only allow products in cart of the same vendor in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce, product, vendor

I have written a function in my `functions.php` file of my child theme in my WoocCmmerce store.

The validation on the `add to cart` button checks if all products in the cart come from only 1 vendor.

- If the products come from one vendor it will add the product.
- If the products come from separate vendors a notice should display a warning.

This function does not work correctly as the notice only displays when i manually refresh the page. It should display the notice immediately. Can anyone help me?

Here's my code below:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'martfury_child_enqueue_scripts', 20 );
function martfury_child_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'martfury-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    if ( is_rtl() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'martfury-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css', array(), '20180105' );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', function( $is_allow, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $product = get_post( $product_id );
    $product_author = $product->post_author;

    //Iterating through each cart item
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $cart_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $cart_product = get_post( $cart_product_id );
        $cart_product_author = $cart_product->post_author;
        if( $cart_product_author != $product_author ) {
            $is_allow = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( !$is_allow ){
        // We display an error message
    wc_add_notice( __( "Well, you already have some item in your cart. First checkout with those and then purchase other items!", "wcfm-ecogear" ), 'error' );
        
    return wp_redirect($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url());
    }
    return $is_allow;
    
}, 50, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some of the steps you apply are unnecessary, this should suffice

- [get_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) - Retrieves post data given a post ID or post object
- Explanation via comment tags added in the code

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {       
    // Cart NOT empty
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // Retrieves post data given a post ID or post object.
        $product = get_post( $product_id );
    
        // Post author
        $product_author = $product->post_author;
    
        // Flag, by default false
        $flag = false;

        // Loop trough cart
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // Get product ID
            $cart_product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

            // Get post
            $cart_product = get_post( $cart_product_id );
            
            // Post author
            $cart_product_author = $cart_product->post_author;
            
            // Condition NOT equal
            if( $cart_product_author != $product_author ) {
                $flag = true;

                // Break loop
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // True
        if ( $flag ) {
            // Add notice    
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Products in the cart have to come from only 1 vendor', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

            // NOT passed
            $passed = false;
        }
    }
    
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```